# Seat friends at a dinner table

Tags: probability, permutations

**I have the following question:**

At a squared table I seat $8$ friends of mine.

At each side, I place two friends.

Always two friends know each other.

What's the probability that no friend knows it's sided, neighbor?

**I tried to solve it by:**

- Calculating all different seating possibilities: $4!$ $\Rightarrow 24$
- And writing down all options on paper where no side neighbors know the other side neighbor. For that, I got 9 options.

So I guess my final result is  $$\frac{9}{4!}\Rightarrow 0.375$$

$37.5\%$ that none of the side neighbors knows the other side neighbor.

**Is this correct? How would I calculate the count of all possible seating options where no side neighbor knows each other?**

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of "Always two friends know each other"?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "Always two friends know each other"? (It certainly does not mean "Every two friends know each other", or else the problem would then be trivial.)

Comment: It's 4 couples of friends that know each other. I hope that helps

Comment: So can friends be $A-B$ and $B-C$?

Comment: Or, is it like $A_1, A_2,A_3, A_4, B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4$, where $A_i$ knows $B_i$ (and the other way round) but nobody else knows anyone else?

Comment: Is a person who is not on the same *side* as you, but adjacent to you around a corner of the square treated as being a "side neighbour" ? In other words, is a square table to be treated as a numbered round table ?

Comment: Just found the sequence https://oeis.org/A189849 (the number of ways to seat the $2n$ friends) and the related sequence https://oeis.org/A053871 - there are loads of links for the second sequence, have a look. (I will myself need some time to digest it all.)

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement on user8734617's method:

Exactly $\frac{1}{7}$ of the possible arrangements have a fixed pair $A_1,B_1$ seated together. To see this, given any arrangement with the pair seated together, fix the position of $A_1$ and rotate the other $7$ around the table, giving $6$ other arrangements with $A_1,B_1$ not seated together. This method produces all possible arrangements around the table, so each arrangement with $A_1,B_1$ seated together corresponds to $6$ other arrangements, meaning $A_1,B_1$ sit together with probability $\frac{1}{7}$.

By the same method, of those arrangements with a fixed pair $A_1,B_1$ seated together, $\frac{1}{5}$ have another fixed pair $A_2,B_2$ also seated together, so two fixed pairs sit together with probability $\frac{1}{7 \cdot 5}$; similarly, three fixed pairs sit together with probability $\frac{1}{7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3}$ and four with probability $\frac{1}{7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1}$.

Then we apply inclusion-exclusion: our answer is $$\begin{align}
&1 - \binom{4}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{7} + \binom{4}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{7 \cdot 5} - \binom{4}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3} + \binom{4}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1} \\
&= 1 - \frac{4}{7} + \frac{6}{7\cdot5} - \frac{4}{7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3} \\
&= \frac{3}{7} + \frac{6}{7\cdot5} - \frac{3}{7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3} \\
&= \frac{3}{7} + \frac{5}{7\cdot5} \\ &= \frac{4}{7}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but how is your method so different from the other user's? I mean, the other answer involves very huge numbers

Comment: @Rick They are equivalent, the numbers are huge on my side because everything is multiplied by 8!

Answer (score 1):

Let's label the friends $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4$ where $A_i$ knows $B_i$.

Using inclusion-exclusion formula: the number of ways to put them around the table so that none of $A_i$ sits next to the corresponding $B_i$ is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{4}(-1)^k{4\choose k}^22^kk!(8-2k)!$$

Each term in the sum is the sum over all the sets of $k$ (out of 4) pairs of friends presuming they are together (but not presuming that no others are together). The factor $-1$ comes from the inclusion-exclusion formula itself, one of ${4\choose k}$ comes from the fact that there are that many sets of $k$ pairs, the other ${4\choose k}$ is the number of ways to put those $k$ pairs around the table, $k!$ is to allow for permutations of those $k$ pairs, $2^k$ comes from permuting each pair once they are already seated, and $(8-2k)!$ comes from putting the rest of the people ($8-2k$) around the table arbitrarily.

I am not sure whether there is a shortcut to calculate the total number, but the formula above is short enough to do a manual calculation:

$$8!-4^22^11!6!+6^22^22!4!-4^22^33!2!+1^22^44!0!=40320-23040+6912-1536+384=23040$$

so the probability that no two friends sit together is $\frac{23040}{8!}=\frac{4}{7}$.

I have to say that, now I've got this result, and it looks very simple, I suspect there is an alternative and much simpler calculation. If there is, and if I can get to it, I will update this answer (unless someone else beats me to it).

Comment: Is a square table equivalent to a numbered round table ?

Comment: @trueblueanil In my solution, I do choose to treat all seats as different. So, yes, probably, if I understand right what you mean by "numbered round table". Edit: I now saw your comment under the question, and no: it is not the same. If two people are around the corner to each other, they don't count as neighbours.

Comment: I saw your last comment against the question after I posted my answer. As you say, it will take time to digest !

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is now done and dusted, but here is a direct method avoiding PIE that may appeal.

We needn't bother about numbering $A_1,A_2,...$ or for that matter, the seat numbers.

Just treat them as balls of $4$  colors and follow the chain of pairings to get pairs in unlike colors.

Take any ball, and start pairing. If no pairs are to be similar, $Pr = \frac67\cdot\frac45\cdot\frac23 = \frac{48}{105}$

Alternatively, two pairs each can be alike, e.g. $AC\;\; AC\;\; BD\;\; BD,\; Pr = (\frac67\cdot\frac15)(\frac23) =\frac{12}{105}$

Adding up, ans $= \frac{60}{105} = \frac47$

---

**Added explanation**

Suppose we first pick an $A$. Out of the $7$ other balls, we need to avoid the other $A$, so $\frac 67$, and let's say we paired it with  $C$. If we want no pairs to be similar, the other $C$ can't be paired with the "free" $A$, so $\frac45$ and so on.

On the other hand, for like pairs, having got $AC$, the other $C$ *has* to be paired with $A$, thus $\frac67\cdot\frac15$, and now we have $B\;\;B\;\;D\;\;D\;$ left to pair similarly.